# Seaglass Look and Feel for Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I am new to using Look and Feels in Java. I was trying to add Seaglass look and feel into a java application I was working on but I can't seem to figure out how to use it. I found other people using it and also having problems, although they say there's was fixed.

Here is my Java Code (I'm using Netbeans 8.1 Beta):

```
package pamsorganizer;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class MainProgram extends JFrame {

/**
 * Creates the Main Form for the General Program
 */

public MainProgram() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator();
    jMenuItem3 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenu3 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenu4 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenu6 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenu5 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Organizer");

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText("Welcome to the Organizer");

    jLabel3.setText("<html>\n<p>Welcome to the 's Organizer Application. A Project by James Emerson 2014. If you would like to receive some more benifits out of this application, please sign in or signup.</p>\n</html>");

    jButton2.setText("Signin");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton3.setText("Signup");
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 583, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton3)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addComponent(jButton3))
            .addContainerGap(219, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jTabbedPane1.addTab("Home Tab", jPanel1);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Calander");

    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
        }
    ));
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 584, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jPanel2);

    jTabbedPane1.addTab("Calandar", jScrollPane1);

    jMenu1.setText("File");

    jMenuItem1.setText("jMenuItem1");
    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

    jMenuItem2.setText("jMenuItem2");
    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem2);
    jMenu1.add(jSeparator1);

    jMenuItem3.setText("Exit Application");
    jMenuItem3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem3);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    jMenu2.setText("Edit");
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

    jMenu3.setText("Tools");
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu3);

    jMenu4.setText("Format");
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu4);

    jMenu6.setText("Calendar");
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu6);

    jMenu5.setText("Preferences");
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu5);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jTabbedPane1)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jTabbedPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 365, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    new loginapp().setVisible(true);
}                                        

private void jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    this.dispose();
}                                          

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /*
     * Set the Nimbus look and feel
     */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /*
     * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
     * default look and feel. For details see
     * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
     */
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /*try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainProgram.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainProgram.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainProgram.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainProgram.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }*/
    //</editor-fold>

    /*
     * Create and display the form
     */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new MainProgram().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu3;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu4;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu5;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu6;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator jSeparator1;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

and I have the seaglasslookandfeel-0.2.jar in my source package.

e.g.

```
Source Packages
 -pamsorganizer
    -MainProgram.java
    -seaglasslookandfeel-0.2.jar
```

So my question is, is it possible for someone to assist me in getting seaglass to work in my java application. My errors are bellow:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.loadSystemClass(SwingUtilities.java:1873)
at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:579)
at pamsorganizer.MainProgram$4.run(MainProgram.java:225)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @peeskillet My question is I'm not sure how to use Seaglass. Ill add my errors to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add it to your libraries

Just right click on your Libraries folder in your project explorer, and **Add Jar/Folder**

It should work, I just tested it. Really no need to test though, it works for me every time.

Answer (score 1):

Even after adding jarfile to ur project, you have to import class

```
import com.seaglasslookandfeel.*;
```

I did and it worked for me....

Comment: Thanks, appreciate this comment